# Jquery Как правильно получить значений из json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Как правильно получить значений из json

```
product:  {
"id":48597847,
"price_kinds":[
    {"id":11467,"price_index":1,"value":2},
    {"id":11468,"price_index":2,"value":5}
    ],
"variants":[
    {"prices":[1290.0,999.0],"price":"1490.0","price2":1290.0,"price3":999.0}
    ]
},
```

price_kind значения получить удалось а вот дальше что то делаю явно не так

```
$(function(){
var
  $config = {
    product:  {{ product | json }},
  };
    var
    self        = this,
    prices     = [],
    price_kinds = [];

Events( 'onQuantity_Change' ).subscribe( function( $data ){
  // вытаскиваем правила для типов цен
  $.each( $config.product.price_kinds, function( index, $price_kind ) {
    price_kinds[ $price_kind.price_index ] = $price_kind.value;
  });
  self.price_kinds = price_kinds; 

  // массив цена правило
  // дальше не работает 
  prices[ 0 ] = {
    price: parseFloat( $config.product.variants.price ),
    value: 0,
  };      

  $.each( $config.product.variants, function( index, price ){
    prices[ index +1 ] = {
      price: price,
      value: self.price_kinds[ index +1 ],
    };
 });

  self.prices = prices;

  console.log( 'onBuyButton_Active: ', self.price_kinds );
  console.log( 'onBuyButton_Active: ', self.prices );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли указать индекс массиву "variants".

Попробуйте следующие:

```
 prices[ 0 ] = {
    price: parseFloat( $config.product.variants[0].price ),
    value: 0,
 };
```